# What is this part called?

Tags: derailleur-rear, hanger

I built a new YT Capra yesterday, and it had a part I had not seen before. It was not mentioned anywhere in the instructions, but it was needed to get the rear mech the correct distance from the rear mech hanger.

See in the image below, in the red box. It is a kind of spacer between the rear mech and the rear mech hanger. If I didn't use this, then the mech would hit the frame.

I haven't got a picture of it on its own. It was a small ring with a notch on it. That notch lined up with the notch on the hanger to give it an extra couple of cm. I'm wondering if this is something YT have built especially for this edition (it is not on older ones), and it doesn't exist anywhere else?

[image]

Comment: Probably doesn't have a special name - it'll be "rear derailleur mount spacer"  Possibly its needed because 11 speed?  Or perhaps so they can use an existing style of direct mount hanger without having to create Yet Another Standard ?  This is speculation hence comment.

Comment: Thanks, yes its 11 speed. Based on what you are saying, I would agree, most likely so they did not have to manufacture any new parts.

Comment: There are simply too many hanger options already, so +1 to YT for not making another.

Comment: Yeah, probably just a spacer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's part of the derailer. Most SRAM derailers have a piece like that. They're not really supposed to come off and float freely but sometimes they do anyway. There's not a specific name for it, but if you wanted to buy a new one for this X1 rear derailer, it's part of SRAM pn# 11.7518.014.000, "XX1/X01/X1 Rear Derailleur B-Bolt and Limit Screw Kit". [image: SRAM 2018 spare parts catalog]

Answer (score 7):

Nathan's answer is correct, the part is supplied by SRAM.

For completeness, I did some more digging around, and I found a picture from SRAM that shows the part in action. Note the purple part.

**The name of this part is 'B-Adjust Washer'**

[image]